# Fixing "The SDK seems invalid" error when setting up PyCharm and PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, installation, pycharm

I wanted to set up PyCharm the way this blog post explains: [*Setting up PyCharm for PyQGIS and Qt*](http://nathanw.net/2014/05/10/setting-up-pycharm-for-pyqgis-and-qt/).

I did everything as instructed but when it comes to adding project interpreters I got this error message:

[image: Pycharm]

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be mixing 64 and 32 bit versions of QGIS and/or Python?

Comment: I have 64bit QGIS and I don't know how to check what PyCharm version I have. BTW I got Win7 64bit

Comment: Take a look at this recent post and see if it provides any hints to your situation: http://spatialgalaxy.com/2014/10/09/a-quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis-on-windows/

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked by now I search way to remote debugging with pycharm but nothing worked.

Comment: I had same issue. Check out below url. It helped me https://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/how-to-install-python-on-windows/20111

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618858/why-do-i-get-an-sdk-seems-invalid-error-when-setting-up-my-project-interpreter

Answer (score 3):

From the comments it looked like the asker of this question was able to resolve their problem by reading a blog posting entitled [A Quick Guide to Getting Started With PyQGIS on Windows](http://spatialgalaxy.net/2014/10/09/a-quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis-on-windows/).

In that blog the advice offered seemed to be:

> We only changed the last line, adding the start statement with the
>   path to the IDE (PyCharm). If you save this to something like
>   pycharm.cmd, you can double-click on it to start PyCharm. The same
>   method works for other IDEs, such as PyDev.

Answer (score 3):

The batch script from the [A Quick Guide to Getting Started with PyQGIS on Windows](http://spatialgalaxy.net/2014/10/09/a-quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis-on-windows/) as described in the comments and by @PolyGeo maybe outdated. `The SDK seems invalid` appear in PyCharm 2016.3 by using the script.

I suspect it needs more paths to be included especially (maybe) pip.exe path that exist in `%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Scripts`. So I include that and all other paths (not sure which one is required, maybe some unnecessary, but no time to test 1 by 1):

```
@echo off

SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18
SET PYCHARM="C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\bin\pycharm.exe"

CALL %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat
CALL %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.0.5\etc\env.bat

path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.0.5\lib

SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\bin
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Scripts
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\DLLs
SET QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis

start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

Then it works. Edit the paths to match your environment.

**Anyway, the recent how python/conda installation register PATH or PYTHONPATH in my environment, I follow the same for QGIS python paths in the script.**

Comment: With PyCharm 2018.3.7, this is what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:
I clicked on "file/Reload all from disk", it works ...

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the interpreter python.exe is executable if you're on Linux.

PyCharm will show the same error even if interpreter has been set up fine.