# Adding QGIS-specific Python interpreter to PyCharm on MacOS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pycharm, macos

I have seen the below question, and searched around the internet for a tutorial for instructions on getting Pycharm CE to recognise the QGIS package. I have found which interpreter that QGIS is using, and I can import QGIS in terminal, but Pycharm doesn't recognise it.

[Adding QGIS-specific Python interpreter to PyCharm on Windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/275083/how-to-add-a-qgis-specific-python-interpreter-to-pycharm-on-windows)

Are there any tutorials or specific instructions to get Pycharm and QGIS working together on MacOS?

Comment: Check it out.  https://github.com/Cadasta/cadasta-qgis-plugin/wiki/Development-on-OSX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: For newer versions of QGIS (e.g. 3.12+) see "EDIT" below.

I have utilised the above link that @Fran supplied to add in the appropraite paths to my interpreter without cloning the repository. I have added the following paths to my interpreter:

/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python

Needed for processing framework imports

/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/

It was a bit weird trying to find where to add the paths in PyCharm

Preferences >> Project Interpreter >> Click the down arrow to choose interpreter >> Show All> Select the appropriate interpreter>> then click on the folder (Show paths for the selected interpreter >> Add the paths >> apply.

**EDIT:**
For newer versions of QGIS (e.g. 3.12+) the path to the interpreter (change to 'QGIS-LTR.app' if you are using the long term release) is as so:
`/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/python3.8`
When adding the new new interpreter, check 'Inherit...' to make sure the QGIS relevant packages are included.

Comment: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python doesn't seem to contain a python interpreter in QGIS3.12, am I missing something?

Comment: @LucienS. see my edit for the location of the python interpreter since the MacOS packager has been updated.